# configure varnish ssl with apache on debian 10

Tags: apache, https, debian, varnish, configure

I have configured varnish but the problem is that on the http protocol I return the public folder /etc/www/html
which is not the folder configured in the virtualhost, while varnish is not enabled on the https protocol, can you give me a hand?
these are the files I have in my vps:

virtualhost:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/example.com_error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/example.com_access.log combined
    #SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-Proto https HTTPS=on

    <Directory /var/www/example >
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

  </VirtualHost>

  <VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com


    SSLCertificateFile      /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key

    #RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto expr=%{REQUEST_SCHEME}     

    ProxyPreserveHost       On
    ProxyPass               / http://127.0.0.1:80/
    ProxyPassReverse        / http://127.0.0.1:80/
 </VirtualHost>
```

ports.conf:

```
Listen 127.0.0.1:8080
```

varnish.service:

```
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/varnishd -j unix,user=vcache -F -a :80 -T localhost:6082 -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl -S /etc/varnish/secret -s malloc,2048m
```

default.vcl

```
ackend default {
.host = "127.0.0.1";
.port = "8080";
```

}

the chain should be https and http al varnish on port 80
varnish reports on door 8080
https reports in http with proxy,
where am i wrong?
i'm based my mods on this article [How To Use Apache2 for SSL Termination With Varnish](http://%20%20%20%20https://bash-prompt.net/guides/apache-varnish/)

thanks to those who can help me.
obviously the public site does not currently have varnish enabled

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of this test, I ran the example on the tutorial page and it seemed to work fine.

If your home directory is different from the one in the example, just change the path in the following directives:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/example
```

```
<Directory /var/www/example >
```

And finally, it's a matter of makeing sure your certificates are in the right place:

```
SSLCertificateFile      /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
```

You will probably change those paths the paths of your actual certificate and private key.

After having restarted `systemd` and your services with the following commands, you should be good to go:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart apache2.service
systemctl restart varnish.service
```

### Debugging

If there are any errors you're getting, that prevent you from running this, please share the error messages. At this point it's not 100% clear what's blocking you.

The following command will list al listening ports and the Linux service that is listening to that port. Please use it to figure out if the right services are bound on the right port:

```
netstat -plnt
```

The following command will present all available information on the HTTP request, the HTTP reponse, and the internal processing within Varnish. It does this for the *homepage ("/")*:

```
varnishlog -g request -q "ReqUrl eq '/'"
```

And finally, you can debug your Apache error/acccess logs. Maybe they contain more relevant information:

```
tail -f /var/log/apache2/access.log /var/log/apache2/error.log
```

> Your Apache logs might be located on different path. Please adjust accordingly.

Comment: the configuration files are of my vps I replaced the name of my domain with example.
The problem is that everything works without varnish, when I activate it https responds without varnish and http returns to point to the original apache / var / www / html folder that I removed from all configurations.
Are there commands to understand from which path port 443 and port 80 respond when varnish is active?
thank you

Comment: @lucacarboni I updated my answer, and added some debugging commands. Happy hunting!